# 2 adobe air extensions jar conflicts

Tags: android, eclipse, air, air-native-extension

when building .ane files, you should be careful about naming your resources so no two extensions would conflict each other when used in one app. I know that and it's ok.

I have another kind of conflict problem! you see, in one of the extensions I've been building, I used the external .jar file, Google play services and the extension works like charm. everything was fine until the day that I created another extension which was happened to use the external jar file, Google Play Services again!

when building .ane files, I actually merge any needed external .jar files into the one that I have exported myself from eclipse.

now that I have two different extensions both happen to be using Google Play services external .jar file, when I use them in one app, it won't allow me to package my .apk

the error message says:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
com/google/android/gms/appstate/OnStateListLoadedListener;
    at
com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
```

how can we bypass this kind of confliction?!

Comment: hmm, can you unzip the new jar? i mean, change the file extension from .jar to .zip, then unzip. remove the google play services folder then zipped it then change to .jar.

Comment: I did that already with no luck, you see, in one of the extensions I removed the google-play-services jar file hoping that it would use the jar available in the other extension, but it did not work. maybe a better question is how we can share a same .jar file from two extensions... I think I should open a new question with this topic... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Extension's will not allow same method name's even they are in different extensions. i think that is the mistake you did in making extension's. please look at them and changes method names it will work.

Comment: I cannot change method names as they are in google-play-services.jar which I did not create! Google has created that .jar

Comment: Remove 'Google play services' jar file in one of your ane it then create ane's that way it will work without any errors.